# What is the best way to make text fit inside a circular shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text

I'd like to create something like this:
[image: design peg]

(see design peg)

Ideally, the text should be editable so that any letter combination can be used.

I know I can do it quickly (and keep the text editable) by just using Warp (Photoshop/Illustrator) or Envelope Distort (Illustrator), but it doesn't look as nice. The text is editable though. I included some samples in the linked image above.

I can do something neater and closer to the example by making the shapes manually, but of course the text isn't editable. I'd have to make each letter, from A-Z, manually, in each position (left, middle, right). I included a wireframe example in the linked image above.

**Is there another way for me to do this so I can still keep the text editable, while having  the result look nice and neat like in the design peg?** I was thinking that I'd really just have to do the letter shapes manually, because the design peg looks like that how it was done, but I may be wrong. If so, let me know if you know of a better way to do this. **I may be missing on a tool or effect I don't know about.** Thanks!

P.S. I did try to use WhatFontIs and WhatTheFont to see if I could find the font used in the design peg, but I didn't find anything close. That's another reason why I think it was done manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "*best*" way is to do it all manually. That way you can control stroke widths, curves and the fitting of the characters specifically for your shape.

If you want a quick solution, there's always [LHF Monogram Circle](http://www.letterheadfonts.com/fonts/monogramcircle.php) from [letterheadfonts.com](http://www.letterheadfonts.com)

Comment: Thanks so much, I should've realized that there were special fonts designed for the purpose!

Answer (score -2):

I was sure there was an easier way. In Illustrator this is done using 
"Envelope Distort".
Make a shape
Type your text
Send text to back "Arrange"
Place text on shape
"Object" "Envelope Distort" "Make with Top Object"
Result:
Gif File With Instructions and result 2 sec 11ish frames
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VPIeuhtRn9zQbDuRcshYoKPZSeU0I3Xv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a very old question, and OP already mentioned Envelope Distort. Besides, you should upload images directly to the answer using the "add image" button.

Answer (score -3):

If you want edit text in photoshop you know very well you are looking for particular text like a shape. Easy be relax *and take circle like a path and use type tool* with existing your requirement font size edit in wrap or expand the text then edit as you like.

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/fill-shapes-with-text/