# Wrap text inside sphere

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I'm trying to achieve something like this image in Photoshop CS6:

[image: sphere text]

However I only need two large letters inside. The goal is to have the letters in a standard "squared" font (Arial Black) follow the contour of the sphere and split evenly at 90 degrees in the middle. I've tried liquify and spherize filters with no luck, as well as the text warp tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to make text fit inside a circular shape?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20069/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-text-fit-inside-a-circular-shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very Quick & Easy

Make the text you want then do the following:

```
3D > New Mesh from Layer > Mesh Preset > Sphere
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Other Notes

- You only have 1 frame, so it will render as a single image.
- You can play about with the 3D settings and do things like remove shading, shadows or whatever you want.
- This was done in the current version of Photoshop but is the same for CS6

Answer (score 2):

If Scott's comment isn't what you are looking for and you want it to closer follow the contours of a sphere, you can use the 3D rendering within Photoshop:

[image: Sphere]

1. Create your text layer
2. **3D** → **New Shape From Layer** → ***Sphere***
3. Rotate/Adjust the render settings as necessary (make sure you have the 3D window open)

Answer (score 0):

well you can use **Spherize**

Go to: **Filter** → **Distort** → **Spherize**

for repeating that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and for resizing you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

2 letters

[image]

your text:

[image]